# Unable to find proper error location using sentry for Android release build

Tags: android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, sentry

I am trying to analyse crash log tools for react-native and currently working with Sentry. In debug mode, I am able to find js file name in debug build but in release build it's showing minified name which is of no use.
react-native  run-android --variant=release

is creating index.android.bundle.map in app/build/intermediate/assets/release folder but deleting it before creating apk.

```
Processing react-native sourcemaps for Sentry upload.
> Analyzing 2 sources
> Rewriting sources
> Adding source map references
Uploading sourcemaps for release com.rfpproject-1.0 distribution 1
> Uploading source maps for release com.rfpproject-1.0

Source Map Upload Report
  Minified Scripts
    ~/index.android.bundle (sourcemap at index.android.bundle.map)
  Source Maps
    ~/index.android.bundle.map
```

Sentry is showing error as mentioned below which are not useful:

```
ReferenceError
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Button1

This error is located at:
    in t
    in Connect(t)
    in n
    in s
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in t
app://index.android.bundle in value at line 352:2578
```